# How to add a primary key and foreign key to an existing table in Microsoft SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've created 2 tables, `table123` and `items_ordered`.

- `table123` has 5 columns: `customerid`, `firstname`, `surname`, `city` and `state`
- `items_ordered` has 5 columns `customerid`, `order_date`, `item`, `quantity` and `price`.

I want to create a primary key in `table123` on the `customerid` column and a foreign key in `items_ordered` on the `customerid` column.

Here is the code I used to try and create a primary & foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE table123
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (customerid);

ALTER TABLE items_ordered
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (customerid)
        REFERENCES table123 (customerid);
```

However, when I execute these commands, it says

> Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on nullable column in table 'table123'

How can I fix this? There aren't any null values in the tables either.

P.S. I've tried using this alternative method to create a primary key and foreign key:

```
SELECT table123.customerid, table123.surname, 
       items_ordered.order_date, items_ordered.item, items_ordered.price
FROM table123, items_ordered
WHERE table123.customerid = items_ordered.customerid;
```

The above code gives me a table, linking *customerid* to the customer name and product bought. But is this the correct way of creating a primary & foreign key?

Comment: Well, the error says it all - you **cannot** create a primary key on a nullable column - so make sure in your definition for `table123`, you have `CustomerId INT NOT NULL` - **then** you can define a primary key. And your second attempt is flawed because it should use the **proper ANSI/ISO JOIN syntax** (instead of listing tables, comma-separated, in the `FROM` clause) - and it does **NOT** create a primary and/or foreign key - it just joins two tables on a common column

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could you try this?

```
ALTER TABLE table123
ALTER COLUMN customerid INT NOT NULL
```

Then run :

```
ALTER TABLE table123
ADD PRIMARY KEY (customerid)
```

Then,

```
ALTER TABLE items_ordered
ADD FOREIGN KEY (customerid)
REFERENCES table123 (customerid)
```

You need to change your column definition to not null, and make sure all values are unique as well

Comment: When you create a Primary and Foreign Key, is it meant to create another table?

Comment: Defining Primary and Foreign Keys do not create a new table, they create relationships between the table. Their primary purpose is to ensure data consistency; joins can be performed on other non - primary/non - foreign key columns as well. 

If you create a foreign key which references to primary key of another table, for example `student(stud_id, dept_id) referring to department(dept_id, dept_name)` , one of the things it would do is make sure you can't insert an entry in student table with a non existing dept id.

Answer (score 1):

This normally occurs when you are trying to create a primary key on a column that is allowed to have null values. There may not be any null values in content but the definition still allows for them.

Change the column definition to not allow nulls.